# Getting values from dropdown in google form

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

This is my first selenium project and I am trying to submit this form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdwD1y2eBOoJ-hvk97wDGptfI9oYga8SqtUz7u3nrFbWM7hxw/viewform

I succeeded clicking Multiple choice and Checkboxes but I cant select the Drop down. I tried following with no success. All pointers are welcome:

```
import os
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains 

driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdwD1y2eBOoJ-hvk97wDGptfI9oYga8SqtUz7u3nrFbWM7hxw/viewform")


multiFirst = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"i5\"]/div[3]/div")
multiFirst.click()

checkBocSecond = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"i22\"]/div[2]")
checkBocSecond.click()

dropdownThird = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"mG61Hd\"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]") 
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(dropdownThird).click(dropdownThird).perform()
```

Comment: Selecting the dropdown is working right?

Comment: No that is the one not working.

Comment: I've just checked and I can able to select and also submitted the form

Comment: Ahh your point is I have to select the dropdown first and then click the option?

Comment: Yes @thomas....

Comment: Just tried doing that first and then it works. Thanks can you post an answer that it is required to first expand dropdown and then select. makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasSegato the accepted answer won't work it doesn't have a select tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dropdownThird = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '(//span[@class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent"])[1]')
dropdownThird.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '(//*[@jscontroller="liFoG"]//*[contains(text(),"Option 1")])[2]'))).click()
```

your locator is incorrect use above locator

you have to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium provides Select method for selecting drop downs.

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select 
selection =Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("yourXPATH"))

3 ways to select

1. select_by_index
   selection.select_by_index(yourIndex)
   It selects by index starting from 0 to end of your drop-down.
2. select_by_visible_text 
   selection.select_by_visible_text('yourText') 
   It uses the text inside the drop down.
3. select_by_value 
   selection.select_by_value('Value') 
   It uses the value attribute of drop-down list.